# How can I scale the label size of ggplot2 plots in rmarkdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr, r-markdown

Hello I am generating report with `rmarkdown`
I decided to use `ggplot2` graphs as it seems that `knitr` `rmarkdown` `ggplot2` works better together.

I'd like to globally increase the axis labels, tick label, title of my ggplot2 plots in the `html_notebook` document `rmarkdown::render`'ed.

Can I do this in the `yaml` or by setting something in a global chunk option ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use `theme_update()` in the setup chunk of your rmarkdown document to modify the active theme, overwriting the defaults for all subsequent plots. For example:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
theme_update(# axis labels
             axis.title = element_text(size = 30),
             # tick labels
             axis.text = element_text(size = 20),
             # title 
             title = element_text(size = 50))

```
````

Comment: I wish it weren't the case the R Markdown seems to change the font size, as compared to when one creates the same plot from the console. It seems odd to have it change the font size to something so small.

Answer (score -1):

Adding `theme_bw(base_size = 8)` helped me to scale the whole plot down. Supposedly also works with other themes.